# Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration.jvmHeapPressureMetrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to upgrade Spring-boot from 2.2.5.RELEASE to 2.6.6 and I am encountering few issues with `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency. This service runs in a container environment and it is important to get the endpoint actuator/health to be working. As of now service runs appropriately without the actuator dependency.

Here is the pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper</name>
    <description>APS FDS LATAM FOREX SAP API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
        <strati.bom.version>11.0.10</strati.bom.version>
        <strati.forklift.bom.version>3.18.0</strati.forklift.bom.version>
        <strati.forklift.meghacache.version>3.9.25</strati.forklift.meghacache.version>
        <strati-af-framework-bom.version>4.1.0</strati-af-framework-bom.version>
        <strati-af-iam-bom.version>4.1.0</strati-af-iam-bom.version>
        <strati-af-iam-authz-bom.version>4.1.0</strati-af-iam-authz-bom.version>
        <strati-af-security-iam-api.version>2.2.4</strati-af-security-iam-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>-->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId> <artifactId>azure-client-authentication</artifactId> 
            <version>1.6.10</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId> 
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId> <version>2.1.6</version> 
            <scope>runtime</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId> <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.1</version> </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--            <exclusions>-->
<!--                <exclusion>-->
<!--                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>-->
<!--                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>-->
<!--                </exclusion>-->
<!--                <exclusion>-->
<!--                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>-->
<!--                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>-->
<!--                </exclusion>-->
<!--            </exclusions>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
            <version>[2.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The Strati BOM <dependency> <groupId>io.strati</groupId> <artifactId>strati-af-tomcat8-bom</artifactId> 
            <version>${strati.bom.version}</version> <type>pom</type> </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>io.strati.ioc</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>strati-af-ccm-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.4.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.strati.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>strati-af-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${strati-af-framework-bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.strati.base</groupId>
            <artifactId>strati-af-iam-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${strati-af-iam-bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.strati.base</groupId>
            <artifactId>strati-af-iam-authz-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${strati-af-iam-authz-bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.strati</groupId>
            <artifactId>strati-af-security-iam-api</artifactId>
            <version>${strati-af-security-iam-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- The Forklift BOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.strati</groupId>
            <artifactId>strati-af-forklift-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${strati.forklift.bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!--Forklift megacache dependencies -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.walmart.strati.forklift</groupId>
            <artifactId>forklift-meghacache</artifactId>
            <version>${strati.forklift.meghacache.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.walmart.strati.forklift</groupId>
            <artifactId>forklift-cache-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${strati.forklift.meghacache.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bettercloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>vault-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-vault-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.12</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and here is the stack trace

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --< ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper:ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper >--
[INFO] Building ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.6:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper >>>
[WARNING] The artifact org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:jar:1.3.0.Final has been relocated to org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.3.0.Final
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\p0p01qj\workspace\ExchangeRateService\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.6:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.6:run (default-cli) @ ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.6)

2022-04-21 17:14:17.693  INFO 39400 --- [           main] c.w.f.d.f.p.ForexPaymentsApplication     : Starting ForexPaymentsApplication using Java 1.8.0_25 on LEUSX2010203737 with PID 39400 (C:\Users\p0p01qj\workspace\ExchangeRateService\target\classes started by p0p01qj in C:\Users\p0p01qj\workspace\ExchangeRateService)
2022-04-21 17:14:17.706  INFO 39400 --- [           main] c.w.f.d.f.p.ForexPaymentsApplication     : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2022-04-21 17:14:22.313 ERROR 39400 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration.jvmHeapPressureMetrics
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.walmart.finance.dataservices.forex.payment.ForexPaymentsApplication.main(ForexPaymentsApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:494) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:443) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:154) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration.jvmHeapPressureMetrics
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:524) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:513) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:436) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jvm.JvmHeapPressureMetrics
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:532) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:520) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        ... 21 common frames omitted

2022-04-21 17:14:22.327  WARN 39400 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$$Lambda$293/2114629072.apply(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:873) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:861) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:848) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:788) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
        at com.walmart.finance.dataservices.forex.payment.ForexPaymentsApplication.main(ForexPaymentsApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/JvmHeapPressureMetrics
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jvm.JvmHeapPressureMetrics
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        ... 26 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:08 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-21T17:14:22-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.6:run (default-cli) on project ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I am clearly missing something here, can you please review and let me know what's wrong with this ?.

Comment: You cannot just upgrade Spring Boot when using Spring Cloud. Spring Cloud versions are tied to version ranges of Spring Boot. Hoxton doesn't work with Spring Boot 2.6. To make things worse you are even including a Spring Boot 2.1.3 dependency (the test one). You are also including azure cloud dependencies which might pull in conflicting versions as well.

Comment: No we are not using Spring Cloud in this project, it's just a property i haven't removed after the upgrade. I can update the test version of 2.1.3's scope to provided and it shouldn't cause a problem. Azure cloud dependencies did not pull any spring framework related dependencies that should cause this problem.

Comment: Azure is using cloud, so you are, indirectly, using Spring Cloud. It also looks like your own code is the culprit. Do you have an `@ConditionalOnMIssingBean` in your `ForexPaymentsApplication`? It at least looks like that and it looks like improper use of that annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your response Deinum. I fixed the problem, problem was with micrometer-core package, somehow dependency added was of version 1.1.1 however what spring-boot 2.6.6 should pull 1.8.4. I have updated the dependency tree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if others face the problem, but just in case, I fixed the problem.  For some reason, Maven pulled micrometer 1.1.1 dependency for Spring-boot 2.6.6 instead of 1.8.4 dependency, not sure why this happened. I added specifically micro-meter 1.8.4 and issue is resolved. Here is the earlier pom dependency which had 1.1.1 dependency

````
[INFO] 
[INFO] --< ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper:ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper >--
[INFO] Building ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:jar:1.3.0.Final has been relocated to org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.3.0.Final
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper ---
[WARNING] The artifact org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:jar:1.3.0.Final has been relocated to org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.3.0.Final
[INFO] ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper:ap-fds-latam-forex-payments-sap-wrapper:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:jar:1.6.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.6:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.21.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.18:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4:test
[INFO] +- com.azure:azure-storage-blob:jar:12.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-classes:jar:2.0.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-x86_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:linux-aarch_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-x86_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:osx-aarch_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:windows-x86_64:2.0.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.azure:azure-storage-common:jar:12.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:1.0.17:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.17:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        |     \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.75.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.17:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- io.projectreactor.netty.incubator:reactor-netty-incubator-quic:jar:0.0.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |        |  \- io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-native-quic:jar:linux-x86_64:0.0.26.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |        |     \- io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-classes-quic:jar:0.0.26.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |        \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http-brave:jar:1.0.17:runtime
[INFO] |  |           \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.13.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |              \- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.13.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |                 \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave:jar:2.16.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |                    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.16.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |                       \- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.23.2:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.12:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics:jar:0.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.14.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] +- io.strati.servlet:strati-af-framework-bom:pom:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.strati.base:strati-af-framework-bom:pom:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-boms-version:jar:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-impl:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.strati:strati-af-spi:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-api-base:jar:3.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- io.strati:strati-af-api-chain:jar:3.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.strati:strati-af-api-concurrent:jar:3.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-api-constants:jar:3.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-api-exception:jar:3.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-api-functional:jar:3.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-api-message:jar:3.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-api-runtime-context:jar:3.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-configuration-api:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati.messaging:strati-af-messaging-jms-client-api:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-metrics-api:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-txn-marking-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-policy-api:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-cache-api:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-query-dsl-api:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-solr-api:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.strati:strati-af-solr-client-api:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- com.walmart.strati.forklift:solrj-shaded-lib:jar:1.0.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.strati:strati-af-messagebus-api:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-runtime-context:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.strati:strati-af-runtime-discovery:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-utilization:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-common:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-google:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-http:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-jackson:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-joda:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-reactivex:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.strati:strati-af-reflection:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.strati:strati-af-servlet:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.strati:strati-af-ecv-check:jar:4.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.strati:strati-af-api-event:jar:3.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.strati.base:strati-af-iam-bom:pom:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.strati:strati-af-iam-client:jar:6.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-iam-common:jar:6.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.strati:strati-af-iam-herasaf:jar:6.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.strati:strati-af-iam-client-core:jar:6.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.strati.base:strati-af-iam-authz-bom:pom:4.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.strati:strati-af-iam-authz-client:jar:6.9.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.strati:strati-af-iam-principal-attr-ext-pip:jar:6.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.strati:strati-af-security-iam-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- io.strati:strati-af-forklift-bom:pom:3.18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-couchbase:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.walmart.strati.forklift:couchbase-client-shaded-lib:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-datastore-impl:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-datastore-api:jar:3.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.walmart.strati.af:service-registry-client:jar:0.47.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.walmart.strati.af:chain:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-query-dsl-impl:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.walmart.strati.forklift:querydsl-jpa-shaded-lib:jar:1.0.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-jpa:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:9.4.1.jre8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-cassandra:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.walmart.strati.forklift:datastax-client-shaded-lib:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.6.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jdbc:ucp:jar:12.1.0.2.0.p21187539:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:12.1.0.2.0_p19158500:compile
[INFO] |  +- JDBCDrivers.Informix:ifxjdbc:jar:4.10.JC7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-meghacache:jar:3.9.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-impl:jar:3.9.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.strati:strati-af-persistence-api:jar:3.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-impl-libs:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:crypto-jpa-shaded-lib:jar:1.0.40:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.walmart.strati.forklift:spymemcached-shaded-lib:jar:1.0.40:compile
[INFO] +- com.walmart.strati.forklift:forklift-cache-impl:jar:3.9.25:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.bettercloud:vault-java-driver:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.supercsv:super-csv:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.15:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.664 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-21T16:04:03-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```
````